# How to use the multiple collider in cube object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I use the multiple collider in cube object?

I have one cube object. If you touch the right side Action A happens; if you touch the left side Action B happens.

I attached two box colliders on the cube object.

My source code is:

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)){
            // I catch the event that any collider is clicked;
            actionA(hit.transform.gameObject);
            // or
            actionB((hit.transform.gameObject);// How can I tell which collider is clicked????
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do in these cases is to add some Children GameObject, each with only a Box Collider. You could change the name of the GameObjects compare them in your code. Something like this:

- Cube

  - Side A
  - Side B

[image: Cube with Inspector]

[image: Side A]

[image: Side B]

Then, in your code, after your raycast, you compare with

```
if(hit.gameObject.name.Equals("Side A"))
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: As an aside, if you have a lot of instances of the same behavior for different objects (for example if this cube is an enemy object and one side is a weak side and the other strong or something) you can use "tag" instead of "name" to apply the behavior more broadly without having redundant of confusing naming hierarchies.

Comment: Thank you it solves my problem like a miracle. I needed to change hit.gameObject.name.Equals("Top Collider") -> hit.transform.gameObject.name.Equals("SideA")

Comment: @whitebear please select this answer as the "Accepted answer", if it helped solve your problem. That way, we can focus on other, still unanswered questions. Thanks!

Comment: @whitebear you are absolutely right. my bad, corrected.

Comment: Thanks @RJD I select the anser as Accepted answer